# What is the space complexity of declaring an array with a "constant" size?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, big-o, space, space-complexity

When you declare "lastIndexes" array it is always going to have the size "26". It won't change depending on the inputs. So does that mean this operation is O(1) constant space? Please ignore partitions array, I am curious just with the "Array(26)" operations.

Update: I don't want to know the TIME complexity of the operation, how much memory is this going to cost?

```js
var partitionLabels = function(S) {
    const partitions = [];
    const lastIndexes = new Array(26);
    
    for(var i = 0; i < S.length; i++){
        lastIndexes[S.charCodeAt(i) - 97] = i;
    }
    
    let start = 0;
    while(start < S.length){
        let maxIndex = lastIndexes[S.charCodeAt(start) - 97];
        let curr = start;
        
        while(curr != maxIndex){
            maxIndex = Math.max(maxIndex, lastIndexes[S.charCodeAt(curr++) - 97])
        }
        
        partitions.push((curr - start) + 1);
        start = curr + 1;
    }
    
    return partitions;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

O(1) means a constant space complexity, irrespective of the input or any other variable.

Even if your array size was of 100000 instead of 26, it would still be O(1) as your array size doesnt depend on any other value.

Comment: I see, thank you! It made sense to me but every time I asked someone they confused the heck out of me.

Comment: @Moe you have got 2 answers on the post. Can you mark one of them as solution whichever you think is best to close the question.